# If statement not working despite having triggered the appropriate boolean value | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to get this if statement to execute when `good_view_list` is `True`, I'm aware that it's a list but whenever I print out its boolean it gives me a `True` value (I'm assuming because there are strings inside), why then doesn't this `if good_view_time is True:` if statement work if `good_view_time` is in fact `True`.

I'm aware of other alternatives, just want to know why THIS one doesn't work.

```
good_view_time = ['https://www.instagram.com/p/CKmTcvmHYkY/', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CKcOxtlHJsy/' , 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CKpHBAcHkhl/']

#returns True
print(bool(good_view_time))

if good_view_time is True:
    for post in good_view_time:

        print(post)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bool(good_view_time)` returns `True`, but `good_view_time` itself is a list, it can't be *literally* `True`. `good_view_time` is *not* `True`, but converting it to Boolean gives True because non-empty lists are truthy. In the same vein, `bool("Hello") is True`, but the string `"Hello"` itself is most definitely not equal to True (why would it be? It's a string!), nor is it exactly equivalent to `True` as the `is` operator would check.

So, you should be comparing:

```
if bool(good_view_time) is True:
```

Or, which is equivalent:

```
if good_view_time:
```